# Request for tag spelling correction: [differiential-pair] [sic]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Please could the tag [differiential-pair](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differiential-pair) have its spelling corrected to **differential-pair**.

(There are currently only five questions using that tag.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

I merged the tag into [differential-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-amplifier) so it is gone now.

Comment: Differential pair signals don't necessarily mean the input signals to a diff amp though. RS-485 or CAN use differential signals. Tagging some question about converting UART to RS-485 with [tag:differential-amplifier] seems strange.

Comment: @Lundin I merged the tag but did not make it a synonym, so there is no "differential-pair" tag. A user could either create such a tag or more likely use the existing "differential" tag (which is also not a synonym of "differential-amplifier".